# iframe Youtube video not displaying

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

Update: I just tried opening the files in Chrome instead of Firefox.  The video appears in Chrome, but not Firefox.  Does anyone know why?

I am a beginning website designer trying to embed a youtube video in my webpage, but for some reason it is not showing up.  There is a ghost object taking up the same amount of space as the video would, but the video itself is not showing.  I have researched how to embed videos, and I do not understand why it's not working.  Any tips are appreciated!

HTML:

```
<iframe class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oTSGrL04wwU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
iframe.video{
    position: relative;
    left: 260px;
    padding: 20px;}
```

Comment: it work perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/kp804yxx/   you can check here

Comment: It's just a blank space when I use the code on my website.  Any ideas why?  Could the video's privacy settings be causing an issue?

Comment: it's because you use left: 260px; with position: relative;  remove left and everything will be fine https://jsfiddle.net/kp804yxx/1/

Comment: The video content was already not showing up before I added the css...  Unfortunately fiddling with the css does not seem to solve my problem (I am only using the css to center the video content within my overall wrapper design).

Comment: Update: I just tried opening the files in Chrome instead of Firefox.  The video appears in Chrome, but not Firefox.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: To make iframe center you can use max-width and then margin: 0 auto; it will be better then position: relative; and Left value, and about Firefox issue if iframe working in Chrome then their is no issue with is

Comment: I tried the code in Firefox on my work machine and it worked fine.  My Firefox must need to be updated or something...weird.  Thank you for all your advice and letting me know I wasn't crazy!